# Do I have to use glGenVertexArray in opengl

Tags: opengl, vertex-array

```
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
```

As you can see from the above code, some tutorials use this before using opengl. But a tutorial that I am following, directly uses `glGenBuffers` method and it works just fine. Hence I am totally confused what `glGenVertexArrays`. It is sad that it defines how buffer is used, but noone says in what way. Can you help me understand ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the OpenGL version. Beginning with the OpenGL-3 *core* profiles having a VAO is mandatory. To stay compatible with older code most developers just throw in the snippet you found there at the beginning to have a VAO lying around to catch all the VBO state.

Answer (score 2):

#### Vertex Array Objects (VAOs) are state containers.

In older versions of GL, things like `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` were global state. However, beginning with GL3 they became tied to VAOs.

*Compatibility* profiles still allow you to treat vertex array states as global state, but 3.1 (without the `GL_ARB_compatibility` pseudo-extension) and 3.2+ *core* profiles require you create and have a non-zero VAO bound any time you make a call like `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` or `glDrawArrays (...)`. Otherwise, you wind up with a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

Answer (score 2):

From openGL 3.2+ using a VAO is mandatory unless you use a compatibility profile.

Each VAO stores the index buffer (ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER) and per attribute bindings.

In [one of my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27044372/731620) I provided a portion of the state stored in each VAO.